# Disable PDF and SVG download options in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts v4.0.3 with exporting.js in my web app, and I want to be able to just provide the end user with the following download options:

- Download Chart as JPG
- Download Chart as PNG

However, the standard options are:

- Print Chart
- Download Chart as JPG
- Download Chart as PNG
- Download Chart as PDF
- Download Chart as SVG Vector Graphic

How can I customise it so that it just gives the user JPG and PNG options?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does it matter if they can export it to PDF or print?  Naturally they can print the JPG or PNG they save anyway or turn those into a PDF.

Answer (score 26):

You can manually set `exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems)) to contain whatever buttons you want.

You'll want to set it to only contain JPG and PNG like this (short form, `textKey` only):

```
menuItems: ['downloadPNG','downloadJPEG']
```

Or for more explicit function calls (long form with objects and `onclick`):

```
menuItems: [{
    textKey: 'downloadPNG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart();
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/jpeg'
        });
    }
}]
```

As in these JSFiddle demonstrations: [short form](https://jsfiddle.net/a9bvusny/) and [long form](https://jsfiddle.net/h97xk1v3/).

The default for `exporting.js` is:

```
menuItems: [{
    textKey: 'printChart',
    onclick: function () {
        this.print();
    }
}, {
    separator: true
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadPNG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart();
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadJPEG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/jpeg'
        });
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadPDF',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadSVG',
    onclick: function () {
        this.exportChart({
            type: 'image/svg+xml'
        });
    }
}]
```

The additional ones for `export-data.js` are:

```
menuItems: [{
    textKey: 'downloadCSV',
    onclick: function () {
        this.downloadCSV();
    }
}, {
    textKey: 'downloadXLS',
    onclick: function () {
        this.downloadXLS();
    }
},{
    textKey: 'viewData',
    onclick: function () {
        this.viewData();
    }
},{
    textKey: 'openInCloud',
    onclick: function () {
        this.openInCloud();
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove unnecessary options the following way:

```
if (Highcharts.getOptions().exporting) {
    let contextButton = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton;
    contextButton.menuItems = contextButton.menuItems.filter((item) => {
        return item.textKey === 'downloadJPEG' || item.textKey === 'downloadPNG';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In chatOptions we can write [customize options](https://jsfiddle.net/pvskrishna/qbwgsxd6/2/) in the high-charts menu we can customize the dropdown options.
In chart options, we can write like:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
      contextButton: {
        menuItems: ['downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG', 'downloadPDF', 'downloadSVG'],
      },
    },
}
```

Example: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/pvskrishna/qbwgsxd6/3/)
Reference: [click here](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41046#p142931)