# How can we add chart context menu in highcharts-angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts

In my highcharts-angular application need to be display chart context menu as show in below image.

[image]

I have gone through this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic example but this whole code in JavaScript & jQuery. But here I need same functionality in highcharts-angular.

My sample code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6h17i.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: The question is how to make a dropdown menu or all this functionality in list?

Comment: As I understand Highchart brings you an API to work with chart. Dropdown menus is not a highchart library responsibility. You need to implement it by your own or use some third party module for it

Comment: yeah Danil Gudz, as I shown in above image I need to give chart context menu to user to see data in different formates. looks I need all functionality Danil Gudz. Have to add dropdown & its functionality.

Comment: @DanilGudz, any sample code snippets please if possible? I have been trying in some ways but not get succeeded yet :(.

Comment: idk, it depends on your project, if you have ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap or angular-material –there is a dropdown component there, for angular-material it seems to be named as `menu`. If you have no such "ui-kit" then search for separate dropdown menu in npm and use it. If there is time then try to make it yourself. Talking about all the functionality in dropdown list – it should be separated question about each menu item. One about pdf, etc. And do it one by one, try reading sources from highchart example and docs. Append your half-working code in question and then you'll get some more help

Comment: Yeah, Will try that way @DanilGudz. Thank you for valuable inputs.

Answer (score 4):

Highcharts context menu requires to import and initialize `exporting` and `export-data` modules:

```
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import * as HighchartsExportData from "highcharts/modules/export-data";

HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
HighchartsExportData(Highcharts);
```

**Your app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import * as HighchartsExportData from "highcharts/modules/export-data";

HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
HighchartsExportData(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: null,
      plotBorderWidth: null,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: "pie"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Browser market shares in January, 2018"
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: "{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>"
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: "pointer",
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %"
        },
        showInLegend: true
      }
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Brands",
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [
          {
            name: "Chrome",
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
          },
          {
            name: "Internet Explorer",
            y: 11.84
          },
          {
            name: "Firefox",
            y: 10.85
          },
          {
            name: "Edge",
            y: 4.67
          },
          {
            name: "Safari",
            y: 4.18
          },
          {
            name: "Sogou Explorer",
            y: 1.64
          },
          {
            name: "Opera",
            y: 1.6
          },
          {
            name: "QQ",
            y: 1.2
          },
          {
            name: "Other",
            y: 2.61
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**Demo:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/2z2y2n07w0

Comment: while trying as you suggested I am seeing this error `[ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof import("d:/Angular/Angular6WithHighcharts/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting")' has no compatible call signatures. [2349]` any idea please ?

Comment: looks some versioning issue ?

Comment: Does this error occur in your local environment or an online demo?

Comment: Its in my local environment @Wojciech Chmiel  but made few changes its working like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: It's pleasure to hear that. If you like this answer please mark it as a correct one, thanks.

Comment: Sure @ Wojciech Chmiel, with few extra code changes I have been mode due to above posted error by me & we can see complete code here  [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6h17i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6h17i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: There is any way to remove few options from chart context menu @Wojciech Chmiel ?

Comment: Looks we can do. please have a look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232921/disable-pdf-and-svg-download-options-in-highcharts] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232921/disable-pdf-and-svg-download-options-in-highcharts)

Comment: Yes, we can, check this: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution. Though latest highcharts-angular version changed module names, your answer gave me a hint to import additional libs. Now if one needs export context menu, this code snippet should be added to needed component:

`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';

HC_exporting(Highcharts);`

Hope this helps to anyone like me

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation in npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular) one should add these lines to appropriate component for download context button get appeared:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';

HC_exporting(Highcharts);
```